# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). What is the solution

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas, valueerror

from time import time
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def train_classifier(clf, X_train, y_train):
''' Fits a classifier to the training data. '''

```
# Start the clock, train the classifier, then stop the clock
start = time()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
end = time()

# Print the results
print("Trained model in {:.4f} seconds".format(end - start))
```

def predict_labels(clf, features, target):
''' Makes predictions using a fit classifier based on F1 score. '''

```
# Start the clock, make predictions, then stop the clock
start = time()
y_pred = clf.predict(features)

end = time()
# Print and return results
print("Made predictions in {:.4f} seconds.".format(end - start))

return f1_score(target, y_pred, pos_label='H'), sum(target == y_pred) / float(len(y_pred))
```

def train_predict(clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
''' Train and predict using a classifer based on F1 score. '''

```
# Indicate the classifier and the training set size
print("Training a {} using a training set size of {}. . .".format(clf.__class__.__name__, len(X_train)))

# Train the classifier
train_classifier(clf, X_train, y_train)

# Print the results of prediction for both training and testing
f1, acc = predict_labels(clf, X_train, y_train)
print(f1, acc)
print("F1 score and accuracy score for training set: {:.4f} , {:.4f}.".format(f1 , acc))

f1, acc = predict_labels(clf, X_test, y_test)
print("F1 score and accuracy score for test set: {:.4f} , {:.4f}.".format(f1 , acc))
```

clf_A = LogisticRegression(random_state = 42)
train_predict(clf_A, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
print('')

Comment: Please use the code tags for the whole code. When will you get the error? Do you have a more detailed error message? Can we get the data to test it ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

You are simply splitting your data into test/train and then fit data inside model that why it give you Error" Input Contains Nan Values".

First you need to apply pre-processing after reading dataset using pandas to remove Nan Values inside Dataset. and then move towards splitting data and then building model.

for this to be done you can follow [Link](https://datatofish.com/dropna/#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Drop%20the%20Rows,dropna().&text=You%20may%20have%20noticed%20that,is%20currently%202%20and%204.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves the problem,
try to drop the entries with missing values using:

```
YOUR_DATAFRAME.dropna()
```